# How to use else if with in else if in jquery?

Tags: jquery

am using if loop for jquery. everything working perfectly except one else if.. I have mentioned that block.  My loop structure is,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($.browser.mozilla){
if($('div').hasClass('js-form-item-panes-delivery-select-address')){
$('div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper').css('top','596px !important');

}
}

else if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
    if($('div').hasClass('js-form-item-panes-delivery-select-address')){
    $('div#uc-address-panes-delivery-zone-wrapper').css('top','547px');

    }
    else if ($('div').hasClass('.messages.messages--error')){
        $('details#quotes-pane').css('color','green');

    }

}else{

}
});
```

Comment: You need to mention the actual conditions if you want us to understand what is going on and help.

Comment: I assume you've simplified your code for the purpose of this question, but you may have gone a little too far. That code looks like it will work, as written, so the problem is probably trusted to the surgical conditions you're checking. Can you share those?

Comment: It seems true could you share more detail?

Answer (score 0):

First problem
You must add close tag 
At the end of your code
  **);**
I checked you code work fine
But if the problem is in logic
Please enter values for checking